# WPF SciCharts Stacked Column Side by Side Spacing

Tags: wpf, scichart

I've noticed a weird issue with SciCharts on WPF and am trying to understand if the issue is something within our control or not.

I'm noticing, in particular, that the spacing between Stacked Column Series groupings is weird.  If you load up the SciCharts v.4.x Example and look at the "Stacked Column Side By Side" example, you can see this.  Simply go from having everything checked to unchecking "China."  Every single other bar (despite that China is no longer selected, freeing up more margin around the groups) is now narrower, even though there is more space to occupy.

In my own usage, I have noticed that the spacing gets VERY unusual, despite the fact that nothing can be turned on/off.  There are data points for everything and there is still a large gap, despite setting Spacing to Relative and 0.01 and the DataPointWidth to 1.0.

I haven't checked the v.5.x examples yet, but I know that the issue is showing up with our usage of 5.2.1.x assemblies.

Is there any other way of expanding or overriding spacing between groups?  It gets terribly sad when we are showing 9 groupings (18 bars; 2 data points for each group, so 9 categories or groupings) and we have more whitespace around the bar groupings than the width of the bars themselves.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would suggest is to update. The latest official release is [SciChart WPF v5.4](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-wpf-v5-4-released-plus-dotnet-core/) and [SciChart WPF v6 is in BETA](https://www.scichart.com/beta-edition-of-scichart-wpf-sdk-6-now-available/) now to be released soon.

We have fixed hundreds of bugs over the years and Stacked Column spacing has come up several times.

In the latest version, there are properties to control Stacked Column spacing. You will need to check

- StackedColumnRenderableSeries.UseUniformWidth: where true forces all columns to have the same width
- StackedColumnRenderableSeries.DataPointWidth: where 0.0 - 1.0 controls the gap width

Finally, Stacked Column series require that all DataSeries have the same number of points.